# How many ways to put balls in boxes with restrictions?

Tags: combinatorics

There are two questions regarding this problem:

**Suppose we had eight unique and labeled boxes (1-8) and 16 indistinguishable orange balls.**

- **Q1) How many ways to arrange if odd boxes must have an odd number of balls and even boxes have an even number of balls?**
- **Q2) How many ways to arrange if we have 16 indistinguishable yellow balls and want to distribute both orange and yellow?**

I am clueless on where to go from the first part. For the second part, should we just add the balls together such that we have $32$ balls? Then $\dfrac{39!}{7!\times32!}$. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For the first question begin by putting one ball in each of the four odd-numbered boxes. The remaining $12$ can then be distributed in pairs, and the problem is equivalent to asking in how many ways $6$ indistinguishable balls can be distributed amongst the $8$ boxes. This is a standard [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) problem.

Putting one ball in each of the odd-numbered boxes at the beginning and then distributing the balls in pairs ensures that each even-numbered box gets an even number of balls, and each odd-numbered box gets an odd number of balls, and every such distribution can be obtained in this way.

The second problem isn’t clearly stated. If we are supposed to count the arrangements in which each odd-numbered box has an odd number of orange balls and an odd number of yellow balls, while each even-numbered box has an even number of orange balls and an even number of yellow balls, the problem is easy: each allowable distribution of the orange balls can be combined with any allowable distribution of the yellow balls, so the total number of allowable distributions is just the product of the numbers of allowable distributions of orange and of yellow balls. If, however, we are supposed to count the distributions in which each odd-numbered box contains an odd number of balls altogether, and each even-numbered box contains an even number of balls altogether, the problem becomes much more difficult, and I don’t immediately see a nice solution.

Comment: In the second case, the numbers are small enough that one can probably just wing it. There are only 13 possibilities for how many of the odd-numbered respectively even-numbered boxes get an odd number of _orange_ balls, and for each of those outcomes we can count the possibilities with the technique you've already presented (each color reduces to one of 5 different stars-and-bars problems that can be done once and for all), times a few small binomial coefficients to account for the choice of exactly _which_ odd and even boxes it is that get the odd orange balls.

Comment: My apologies. They are two separate restrictions and two separate parts to the question. I edited my original post to clear up the confusion. The second restriction doesn't have anything to do with the distribution of evens and odds.

Comment: @hydra-bslash-0: In that case you can simply count the unrestricted distributions of orange balls and the unrestricted distributions of yellow balls and multiply them to get the total number of distributions.